# No loading/serving of stylesheets - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am attempting SSR with React router's `StaticRouter`.

**express.js** *(server)*

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <App />
    </StaticRouter>
);

res.status(200).send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">${html}</div>
        </body>
    </html>
`);
```

Serving of static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/client")));
```

**App.js** *(shared)*

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router";

export default () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            ...
        </Switch>
    );
};
```

**index.jsx** *(client)*

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

**./styles/Main.scss**

```
.header {
    background-color: #002933;
}
```

I have 2 webpack configurations, 1 for the client & 1 for the server:

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
    entry: {
        app: [
            "eventsource-polyfill",
            "webpack-hot-middleware/client",
            "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
            "react-hot-loader/patch",
            "./client/index.jsx",
        ],
        vendor: [
            "react",
            "react-dom",
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: `${__dirname}/dist/client`,
        ...
    },
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
            }, {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            query: {
                                localIdentName: "[hash:8]",
                                modules: true
                            }
                        }, {
                            loader: "postcss-loader"
                        }, {
                            loader: "sass-loader"
                        }
                    ]
                }),
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            allChunks: true
        }),
    ]
};
```

**webpack.config.server.js**

```
const ExternalsPlugin = require("webpack-externals-plugin");

module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        path: `${__dirname}/dist/`,
        filename: "server.bundle.js",
    },
    ...
    resolve: {
        ...
        modules: [
            "client",
        ],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
            }, {
               test: /\.scss$/,
               loader: 'style-loader!css-loader/locals?module&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExternalsPlugin({
            type: "commonjs",
            include: `${__dirname}/node_modules/`,
        }),
    ],
};
```

I have a JSX file where the `.header` should be applied to:

```
import React from "react";

import Links from "./Links.jsx";
import profilePic from "../../img/brand/profilePic.jpg";

import styles from "../../styles/Main.scss";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header className={styles.header}>
                <img src={profilePic} alt="Professional Picture"/>
                <h5>{this.props.pageName}</h5>
                <Links/>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

This throws the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined
    at Header.render (E:/Documents/Projects/website/client/js/components/Header.jsx:22:30)
    at resolve (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2149:18)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2260:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2234:19)
    at Object.renderToString (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2501:25)
    at E:/Documents/Projects/website/server/config/lib/express.js:204:31
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at p3p (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\lusca\lib\p3p.js:15:9)
    at E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\lusca\index.js:59:28
    at xframe (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\lusca\lib\xframes.js:12:9)
    at E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\lusca\index.js:59:28
    at xssProtection (E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\lusca\lib\xssprotection.js:16:9)
```

When running the application, webpack reports that the stylesheet **has** been loaded:

[image]

**EDIT**

Other than an ES6 import, I have attempted to use CommonJS' `require()` as in [MERN](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/master/client/App.js#L13) but still no look...

When I build my server webpack config, I am now getting the error:

```
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-middleware/node_modules/mime/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './types/standard' in 'E:\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\webpack-dev middleware\node_modules\mime'
 @ (webpack)-dev-middleware/node_modules/mime/index.js 4:26-53
 @ (webpack)-dev-middleware/index.js
 @ ./server/config/lib/express.js
 @ ./server/config/lib/app.js
 @ ./server/server.js
```

I am not sure if this a red-herring or not in this situation or not but thought it worth mentioning here as I am quite lost. Feel as though I am clutching at straws at this point.

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        "es2015",
        "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],
    "env": {
        "server": {
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "css-modules-transform", {
                        "preprocessCss": "./loaders/sass-loader.js",
                        "generateScopedName": "[hash:8]",
                        "extensions": [".scss"]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "production": {
            "presets": [
                "es2015",
                "react",
                "react-optimize",
                "es2015-native-modules",
                "stage-0"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I was attempting to go back to basics and have my babel handle server-side bundling instead of webpack. This was built from a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mattvagni/server-side-rendering-with-css-modules-6b02f1238eb1) for SSR with CSS modules I was kindly linked to by @mootrichard

**EDIT 2**

A few observations which might help...when using an es6 import for stylesheets:

```
import styles from "../../styles/Main.scss";
```

and log `styles` into the console, it returns **undefined** *(evidence that it cannot find the file for some reason)*.

When putting the `<link>` tag in the `head` for the initial page, the `<link>` tag is present in the markup but **not** in the network:

[image]

[image]

However, when navigating to `localhost:8000/app.css`, a positive response with the styling is sent back:

[image]

If the browser can find the bundled version standalone, then why is it not being loaded in my initial page? *(The path is correct)*

Comment: do you see any console.log errors about issues loading stylesheet

Comment: @NagaSaiA no, there is no logs at all

Comment: Your Header.jsx users the word "header" in multiple places. Have you confirmed that the className is the one located at Header.jsx:22:30 (line 22, char 30)? Verifying before moving to next step.

Comment: @DanSorensen I have edited my question and confirmed that the naming of the class is not the issue

Comment: With your class rename does the error reference the property 'theHeader' now?

Comment: The error stack begins in xssProtection module. I wonder if it has any concerns not listed here.

Comment: @DanSorensen yes, the same error references `theHeader` now

Comment: Can you try setting up class instead of className for your header component? https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname

Comment: @jeetaz still nothing. I'm clearly seeing the error now that the style sheet is just not being loaded in by express. I will amend my question to make it clearer

Comment: @jeetaz I have restructured my question to refine the problem

Answer (score 3):

You're having issues because you're using `css-loader/locals` but not using `ExtractTextPlugin` (at least in Development). 
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/59

> Note: For prerendering with extract-text-webpack-plugin you should use css-loader/locals instead of style-loader!css-loader in the prerendering bundle. It doesn't embed CSS but only exports the identifier mappings.

This also explains why you're not able to access the style variable `.theHeader`.

Also, the error `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/app.css".` is a red herring. That is simply the error message you receive if you try to load a stylesheet that doesn't even exist. Which in this case, doesn't appear to be in the directory that you think it is, or isn't actually being generated into a file there.

Since `ExtractTextPlugin` is disabled in development, its likely that your CSS is only being processed by `css-loader/locals`. This might not be a problem in production, since it pairs with `ExtractTextPlugin` but could explain your problems of running this in development.

---

Update:

In looking into this over a little more, I came across a blog post that I think might help you figure out how to configure your CSS to work how you want. https://medium.com/@mattvagni/server-side-rendering-with-css-modules-6b02f1238eb1

I think the main reason for the complication here is that you're sending over the HTML as a rendered string via ReactDOMServer. So there is no where for webpack to inject a `<link>` tag into. You might want to consider just having a `<link>` tag in your header to reference your desired CSS file, since webpack is going to create a single CSS file anyways.

Finally, I highly recommend studying a bit more on webpack, especially since SSR is a newer process and requires doing things a bit differently than many have initially anticipated when webpack was first created.

Comment: That link is helpful, thank you. I have edited my webpack loaders since, please take a look. However, this setup will cause my CSS **not** to be extracted into a single file. I still have the `<link>` tag including the `app.css`. However, that file is no longer present and is returning a status code of 200 so I am confused as to why this is the case? (still, no style is applied & I cannot see the file) I changed my webpack dev config to the other loader as I am not prerendering on the client. Again, I am a novice to webpack here so what do you suggest?

Comment: I have gone off the idea of loading stylesheets in separate ways based on if development or production due to the complexity I am experiencing. I think it will be easier to get setup if the CSS is always loaded from the bundled script.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a little more guidance. Hopefully that can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I have followed the link and edited my babel and webpack accordingly. That link was very helpful into understanding webpack, thank you! I attempted your fix but, as mentioned in the comment, the application no longer runs as it encounters that error thrown by babel. I now also understand that I need the `className` to be set to a variable of styles and not just a string as the selectors are modified so the `className` has to reflect that modification. With that in mind, I am confused as to why you think your fix would work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an error in your webpack.config json hierarchy for you css/sass loaders.  Replace your "loaders" array under module with this "rules" array:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }),
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader"
            })
        },
    ],
},
```

You can see more examples of ExtractTextPlugin usage here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage

Comment: Ah sorry that didn't help.  Would you be able to post the full code of Header.jsx above?  Seems like there is a type error in the render function, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious one from the code posted

Comment: Have amended the question, please look now for the full file

Comment: If on your header element you have the property `className="theHeader"`, does that work?

Comment: Nope, it is accepted an the app will load but no stylesheets are loaded in so no styling applied. See Edit #2

Comment: Hmm, so the styles import isn't working.  In your react component, have you tried importing styles from `../../styles/Main.css` (assuming that is generated to the same location as the .scss).

Comment: Same issue. I have attempted to use CommonJS instead but still nothing. According to [this](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/master/client/App.js), I should be able to import the stylesheet before it is bundled

Comment: How about just `import '../../styles/Main.scss'` in your header component or root component?  Also is the css file itself getting generated by the webpack plugin?  Even if it's not loading in you should be able to see it in your project

Comment: That import statement does not work either. Webpack is definitely bundling the styling. The plugin is bundled from `.scss` to `.css`. Please look at my [repo](https://github.com/Will-GitHub94/website) and see if you can find what it might be

Comment: In your index.html, you have this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/styles.css">`.  Is that file in that directory?  If so, are you seeing that link in your HTML?

Comment: Please look at *Edit #4*